# Debug in Firefox with Aptana Studio 3

Tags: aptana

On my Windows machine, I have Aptana Studio 3 installed. I have a new installation of Firefox 37.0.2 installed along with the add-ons Aptana Debugger 1.7.2 and Firebug 1.8.3.

From Aptana, I choose to debug an HTML page. Firefox opens with a URL like `http://www.aptana.com/?debugger=true&port=63923` and shows the Aptana.com home page. After about 30 seconds I get an error in Aptana:

```
Socket connection error. Please try shutting down and restarting your web browser, and then run 'debug' again. 
Accept timed out
```

Restarting the browser does no good.

Looking at the output of the Aptana debugger add-on in Firefox, I see this:

```
Logger initialized (Tue Apr 21 2015 10:56:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time))
Platform: Firefox v37.0.2 (WINNT)
Debugger: v1.7.2
```

And I see this error:

```
[Tue Apr 21 2015 10:56:45 GMT-0400 (Eastern Standard Time)] TypeError: AptanaDebugger.initDebugger is not a function at chrome://aptanadebugger/content/aptanaLaunch.js:120
```

I am very suspicious of the protocol "chrome" being used with Firefox. I cannot determine where that protocol is coming from though. I have tried this with Firefox being and not being my default browser. Anyone know the fix?

Comment: Have the same problem with Aptana Studio & Firefox (TypeError: AptanaDebugger.initDebugger is not a function at chrome://aptanadebugger/content/aptanaLaunch.js:120) chrome:// is the standard internal protocol of Firefox. You could even view this faulty .js Problems started right after upgrade to 3.6.1 version of studio. Internet Explorer debugger add-on connect but appcrash when trying to do something. Have reinstall Firefox and Aptana Studio several times with no luck. Did you get around this somehow?

Comment: I was never able to solve the problem. I have resorted to debugging my applications using the browser's development tools.

Comment: Oh! I answered amusingly after your comment answer :) By the way, for information, the aptanaLaunch.js and other can be found in .jar-file inside Firefox extension directory of profile (in Win7) "C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\<somechars>.default\extensions\debugger@aptana.com\chrome". Make copy, rename the .jar file to .zip and unpack. Then you can edit any of the .js, pack them back in .zip, rename to .jar, and voila! I debug them in this way :)

Answer (score 1):

Got it at last! The problem is in Firefox/Firebug/AptanaDebugger compatibilities. With some of debugging of these Firefox extensions I've got the information. Strange enough that I couldn't find it with the help of aptanadebugger.err log. So, at first, AptanaDebugger 1.7.2 which comes even with the latest for now 3.6.1 version of Aptana Studio from Appcelerator requires Firefox version 32 or below (as in 33 and higher support for JavaScript Debugger Service was removed, but AptanaDebugger still reies on JDS). And then comes Firebug/AptanaDebugger compatibility. In short, you have to install Firefox version 18 and Firebug 1.9.2 seems OK. Maybe, if any problems with 1.9.2 will go, 1.8.4 version of Firebug must be OK with certainty. Then I switched off Firefox automatic updates through about:config in URL/search string, and set up app.update.auto and app.update.enabled to false, and modified app.update.url to do no update accidentaly through Help-About dialog again )